# Sort row values in ascending order without affecting "zero" in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix as shown below

```
> m
       m-1     m-2     m-3     m-4
1  143.7622 136.5459 150.2471   0.0000
2  154.5759 157.7273   0.0000   0.0000
3  120.0844   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000
4  152.4461   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000
5    0.0000   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000
6  138.0643 123.9677 137.8788 152.7869
7  137.8872   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000
8  154.3439 140.1487 151.1158 154.8959
9  136.0983 139.3603 123.1054   0.0000
10 142.1830   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000
```

I need to sort the rows without affecting the position of the zeros in the matrix. For example, after sorting in ascending order the first row should look like a

```
     m-1     m-2     m-3      m-4
136.5459 143.7622 150.2471   0.0000
```

Could anyone help me in solving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apply` in row-wise fashion ignoring 0's and sorting only non-0 elements.

```
t(apply(m, 1, function(x) {x[x != 0] <- sort(x[x != 0]);x}))

#        m-1      m-2      m-3      m-4
#1  136.5459 143.7622 150.2471   0.0000
#2  154.5759 157.7273   0.0000   0.0000
#3  120.0844   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000
#4  152.4461   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000
#5    0.0000   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000
#6  123.9677 137.8788 138.0643 152.7869
#7  137.8872   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000
#8  140.1487 151.1158 154.3439 154.8959
#9  123.1054 136.0983 139.3603   0.0000
#10 142.1830   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000
```

**data**

```
m <- structure(c(143.7622, 154.5759, 120.0844, 152.4461, 0, 138.0643, 
137.8872, 154.3439, 136.0983, 142.183, 136.5459, 157.7273, 0, 
0, 0, 123.9677, 0, 140.1487, 139.3603, 0, 150.2471, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 137.8788, 0, 151.1158, 123.1054, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 152.7869, 
0, 154.8959, 0, 0), .Dim = c(10L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), c("m-1", "m-2", 
"m-3", "m-4")))
```

Comment: Thank you, Ronak. The solution serves the purpose.